# Confused by if/else statement in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write some code that upon clicking a button allows you to select a captain from a list of team members. Upon clicking the button, the possible team members (arranged in a table) change color and then if you click on one of them, they are assigned as the new captain. I want it so that if you click anywhere else on the screen, the team members go back to their normal color and the page returns to normal.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsfnvwvz/) is a fiddle for my attempt. As you can see, its not working.

My html is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">John Smith</td><td class="captain"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Smith Johnson</td><td class="captain"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Joth Smithson</td><td class="captain"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="button">C</div>
```

And my js is:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var people = $('table tr')
    people.css('background-color','red');
    people.find('td.captain').html('');
    $('html').click(function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        if($('table tr').has(target).length) {
            var newcaptain = $('table tr').has(target);
            newcaptain.find('td.captain').html('C');
            people.css('background-color','');
            $('html').off('click');
        } else {
            people.css('background-color','');
            $('html').off('click');
        }
    });
});
```

What is really puzzling me is that if I remove the statements from the else clause, the if part works as I intend it to. How is this possible?

Comment: If you find yourself putting identical lines of code in both sides of the conditional, then these lines do NOT need to be in the conditional in the first place.  In other words, `people.css('background-color',''); $('html').off('click');` is always going to run no matter what the `if` result.  Pointless.

Comment: Yes- fair comment, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). After the `#button` click method completes the browser works its way up the DOM hierarchy until it hits the root element, looking for other `click` events. Because you add a click event to the `html` tag, the browser finds that and executes it. And as you didn't click a `tr` (you clicked the button), the else statement runs and undoes your css.

If is easy to see if you add an alert just before `$('html).click`:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var people = $('table tr')
    people.css('background-color','red');
    people.find('td.captain').html('');
    alert('button click');
    $('html').click(function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        if($('table tr').has(target).length) {
            var newcaptain = $('table tr').has(target);
            newcaptain.find('td.captain').html('C');
            people.css('background-color','');
            $('html').off('click');
        } else {
            people.css('background-color','');
            $('html').off('click');
        }
    });
});
```

You will see that your button code has worked, but when you close the alert it reverts back straight away.

So you need to stop the event bubbling happening after the button click. The easiest way to do this is to just return false, or call [event.stopPropogation();](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) which tells the browser to stop bubbling:

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var people = $('table tr')
    people.css('background-color','red');
    people.find('td.captain').html('');
    $('html').click(function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        if($('table tr').has(target).length) {
            var newcaptain = $('table tr').has(target);
            newcaptain.find('td.captain').html('C');
            people.css('background-color','');
            $('html').off('click');
        } else {
            people.css('background-color','');
            $('html').off('click');
        }
    });
});
```

I have updated your fiddle to add this: http://jsfiddle.net/jsfnvwvz/7/

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. That kind of a problem hadn't even occurred to me. Thanks for your help and explanation

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button event is sent to it, but also to all parent layers (body, html, document).

To prevent this use `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    ...
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsfnvwvz/6/)!